# How to segregate double and string items, getting invalid cast error

Tags: c#, double, boxing

I have a `Dictionary<string, object>` which has `string` and `double` value for `object`. Now I want to segregate both value type in below code. Currently I am getting **invalid cast error**. How to do this?

```
namespace ConsoleApp26
{
public class Sample
{
    public string SampleName;
    public Dictionary<string, object> SampleValues;
}

public class SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double DoubleValue { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var samples = new Sample
            {
                SampleName = "test",
                SampleValues = new Dictionary<string, object> { 
                    { "t1",  45.08 }, 
                    { "t2", "A String Value" }, 
                    { "t3",  83 } 
                }
            };

            var tuple = GetTuple(samples);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static Tuple<IEnumerable<SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue>, IEnumerable<SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue>> GetTuple(Sample samples)
    {
        var doubles = (from s in samples.SampleValues
                       select new SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue
                       {
                           Name = samples.SampleName,
                           DoubleValue = (double)s.Value
                       });

        var strings = (from s in samples.SampleValues
                       select new SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue
                       {
                           Name = samples.SampleName,
                           StringValue = (string)s.Value
                       });

        return new Tuple<
          IEnumerable<SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue>, 
          IEnumerable<SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue>>(doubles, strings);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should check the type before converting the value into `double` or `string`

Comment: Anyway this error is not throwing in my environment

Comment: @MarcoSalerno `Linq` uses deferred execution, you can see the error when evaluate an `IEnumerable`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski you are true, I tought he wrote a code to let us throw it, I didn't even check ahha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with the data structure is that you have *not only* `string` and `double` but `int`:

```
  var SampleValues = new Dictionary<string, object> { 
    { "t1",  45.08 },             // boxed double value
    { "t2", "A String Value" },   // string value
    { "t3",  83 },                // <- N.B. this is boxed int (83), not double (83.0) value
  };
```

*Casting* **boxed** `int` into `double` *throws exception*:

```
  object o = 83;         // int value (83) which is boxed into object

  double d = (double) o; // <- Exception will be thrown here (invalid cast)
```

Please, note, that *conversion* is OK:

```
  object o = 83;

  double d = Convert.ToDouble(o); // d == 83.0
```

So you can try *filtering out* `String` items and then `Convert` all the rest (`double` and `int` values) into `double`; in your case:

```
  var doubles = samples
    .SampleValues       
    .Where(pair => (pair.Value != null) && !(pair.Value is string)) // not string value
    .Select(pair => new {
       Name  = samples.Name,
       Value = Convert.ToDouble(pair.Value), // which we convert to double
     });

  var strings = samples
    .SampleValues       
    .Where(pair => pair.Value is string)
    .Select(pair => new {
       Name  = samples.Name,
       Value = Convert.ToString(pair.Value),
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) method to filter the values by type, like that (I've used a lambda syntax)

```cs
private static Tuple<IEnumerable<SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue>, IEnumerable<SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue>> GetTuple(Sample samples)
{
    var doubles = samples.SampleValues.Where(s => s.Value is double).Select(s => new SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue
    {
        Name = samples.SampleName,
        DoubleValue = (double)s.Value
    });

    var strings = (samples.SampleValues.Where(s => s.Value is string).Select(s => new SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue
    {
        Name = samples.SampleName, StringValue = (string) s.Value
    }));

    return new Tuple<IEnumerable<SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue>, IEnumerable<SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue>>(doubles, strings);
}
```

For query syntax in your sample you can simply use

```cs
var doubles = from s in samples.SampleValues
        where s.Value is double
        select new SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue
        {
            Name = samples.SampleName,
            DoubleValue = (double)s.Value
        };

var strings = from s in samples.SampleValues
        where s.Value is string
        select new SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue
        {
            Name = samples.SampleName,
            StringValue = (string)s.Value
        };
```

Since `Linq` uses a deferred execution, an invalid cast exception in your sample will be shown only after you iterate the `IEnumerable`. There is also an unclear point with `83` value, since it's an integer

Answer (score 1):

You may check type of object before you cast:

```
var doubles = (from s in samples.SampleValues
               where s.Value is double
               select new SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue
               {
                   Name = samples.SampleName,
                   DoubleValue = (double)s.Value
               });
// same for `string`
```

Or you can use `as`:

```
var sampleValues = (from s in samples.SampleValues
                    select new SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue
                    {
                        Name = samples.SampleName,
                        DoubleValue = s.Value as double? ?? 0,
                        StringValue = s.Value as string
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the key for the strings:

```
private static Tuple<IEnumerable<SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue>, IEnumerable<SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue>> GetTuple(Sample samples)
{
    var doubles = (from s in samples.SampleValues
                   select new SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue
                   {
                       Name = samples.SampleName,
                       DoubleValue = (double)s.Value
                   });

    var strings = (from s in samples.SampleValues
                   select new SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue
                   {
                       Name = samples.SampleName,
                       StringValue = (string)s.Key
                   });

    return new Tuple<IEnumerable<SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue>, IEnumerable<SampleDivideBetweenDoubleAndStringValue>>(doubles, strings);
}
```

But you shouldn't need to cast the values at all. In a Dictionary<string, double> the keys are strings and the values are doubles, no need to cast.

**EDIT**
I didn't see it was <string, object>. Vasily is right. Maybe I should remove my answer, but I'll leave to teach myself not to answer, before I've read the full question.

Comment: this will break at `"t2"` from sample code, as your `s.Value == "A String Value"` and you can't do `(double)"A String Value"`